# UIKit v3 sticky element inside modal?

Tags: modal-dialog, sticky, getuikit

I want to have a `uk-sticky` element inside of a `uk-modal-full` modal, but it does not behave with sticky behavior. As I scroll down the modal, the element scrolls off the screen.

```
<div uk-modal="bg-close: false" class="uk-modal-full">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full" uk-close></button>
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Modal Title</h2>
        <div uk-sticky>
            <!-- Sticky content here. -->
        </div>
        <div>
           <!-- Other content here. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using the `bottom: true` option.

```
<div uk-modal="bg-close: false" class="uk-modal-full">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full" uk-close></button>
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Modal Title</h2>
        <div uk-sticky="bottom: true">
            <!-- Sticky content here. -->
        </div>
        <div>
           <!-- Other content here. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have a sticky element inside of a modal with UIKit?

**UPDATE:**

I tested out having a `uk-sticky` element directly within the `uk-modal` div and worked.

```
<div uk-modal="bg-close: false" class="uk-modal-full">
    <div uk-sticky>
        <h1>Testing Sticky</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full" uk-close></button>
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Modal Title</h2>
        <div uk-sticky>
            <!-- Sticky content here. -->
        </div>
        <div>
           <!-- Other content here. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this is not exactly what I need because I need the content to be within the inner div with the class `uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-full`; otherwise, there is no padding or margin and it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up with a kind of undesirable solution, but it works.

```
<div uk-modal="bg-close: false" class="uk-modal-full">
    <!-- .app-modal-sticky-header is a class I had to use -->
    <!-- in order to apply the background color obtained -->
    <!-- from .uk-modal-dialog. -->
    <div class="uk-modal-body app-modal-sticky-header" uk-sticky>
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full" uk-close></button>
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Modal Title</h2>
        <!-- Sticky content here. -->
    </div>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <!-- Scrollable content here. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a modal header with class `uk-modal-header`, modal footer with class `uk-modal-footer` and then adding `uk-overflow-auto=""` attribute solves this.

This makes body content scrollable and header/footer sticky.

```
  <div id="example-modal" class="uk-flex-top" uk-modal="">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-margin-auto-vertical">
      <button
        class="uk-modal-close-default"
        type="button"
        uk-close=""
      ></button>
      <div class="uk-modal-header">
        <!-- sticky -->
        <h3 class="uk-modal-title">
          Title
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-modal-body" uk-overflow-auto="">
        <!-- scrollable -->
      </div>
      <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
        <!-- sticky -->
        <button
          class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close"
          type="button"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```